# como buscar un dato repetido el mismo mes

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo dos tablas: tuno y tdos
en tuno tengo el numero y en tdos tengo la fecha ejemplo

```
numero  fecha
10      01/01/2021
10      05/01/2021
11      01/01/2021
12      01/01/2021
12      05/01/2021
```

necesito traer solo los numeros 10 y 12, como puedo hacer?
intente lo siguiente

```
select s.numero
from tuno s
inner join tdos cc on cc.idtuno=s.id
where DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%m/%Y') = '01/2021'
GROUP BY cc.fecha HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Comment: Y bajo que regla tenes que traer 10 y 12? o sea, porque? porque no hay nada logio en traer 10 y 12...

Comment: podrias intentar cambiar esto "where DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%m/%Y') = '01/2021'" por where month(fecha) = 1 and year(fecha)=2021 el having siempre dejalo

Comment: gbianchi: necesito traer el 10 y 12 por que son los numeros que se repiten en el mismo mes, osea el 10 tiene la fecha 01 y 05 del mes 01, se entiende?

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.numero
from tuno s
inner join tdos cc
on cc.idtuno = s.id
where (primera condición)
and s.numero in (10, 12)
```

Haces la consulta con las condiciones que te hagan falta y al final agregas una condición que indique si el valor del campo deseado se encuentra en la lista que tendrá los elementos que defines. El **operador in** es el usado en este caso, para obtener lo contrario usa el **operador not in**.

Comment: Creo que en este caso se refería a que necesita el 10 y el 12 porque son los que tienen valores repetidos en el ejemplo que ha puesto. Digo creo, porque todavía no ha respondido al comentario de un usuario preguntándole por qué el 10 y el 12

Comment: El título de la pregunta lo específica: obtener los datos repetidos dentro de un mes

Answer (score 1):

Tu agrupamiento debe ser el numero, año, mes para que te funcione el conteo.

```
    select s.numero
      from tuno s inner join tdos cc 
       on cc.idtuno=s.id
      where DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%m/%Y') = '01/2021'
   GROUP BY snumero, year(fecha), month(fecha) 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```